# Boundary aligned remesh in edit mode

Tags: add-on, remesh

There is a very useful addon called "Boundary aligned remesh" that takes an object containing n-gons and gives them a nice triangular remesh.

I wonder if it would be possible to edit the script so that the input would instead be an n-gon (or multiple n-gons) selected in edit mode, so it's just a fragment of a bigger mesh, and the script would simply ignore the non-selected parts of the mesh.

The script can be found here:

https://github.com/jeacom25b/blender-boundary-aligned-remesh/blob/master/boundary_alinged_remesh.py

Some existing discussion around the topic, although the thread seems to be dead:

https://blenderartists.org/t/boundary-aligned-remesh/1149739

Answer (score 1):

It already does that (through `bm1` variable in the script).
So do the following:

1- Go to 'edit mode'.

2- select your desired part.

3- right click -> Boundary Aligned Remesh

4- Done!

(**Note:** the mesh (*or selected part*) have not to be closed (*like a box*). so you have to either apply on an open selection or remove a face to make the mesh open)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. There's no such option in my context menu. Made a few shapes to test, a circle, for example. Tried with it filled, not filled, removing one edge etc. No success. Could you please post some simple exemplary Blend?

Comment: Have you enabled the addon in the preferences menu?
Which version do you use?
I've also checked the circle case you mentioned and it works. unfortunately imgur is temporarily disabled so I can't share the image

Comment: The addon is enabled, I mean, it works fine in object mode. I use version 1.0 and I'm not aware of any other existing version. You can send stuff via wetransfer link, like this: https://we.tl/t-8Ggr4pyWy4 - it's screenshot from my addon preferences.

Comment: Can you send me your addon's ZIP installer or PY file?

Comment: I've just downloaded the script from the github link that you posted.
this is a use case in edit mode, [see this image](https://imgur.com/a/V0zHb8T)

Comment: I don't understand. Now it's there. Maybe I just accidentally refreshed the script by disabling and then enabling it back. I'm doing exactly the same steps now and it's working. But I'll check later on my other computer. Anyway, thank you for your insight!

Comment: @michalpe please check the answer if it is ok

Comment: I don't understand what happened, but I've just redownloaded the script, did a clean reinstall (remove addon, restart Blender, install addon) and it works in edit mode. Something got messed up before.